# Rearrange sections of text lines to columns for printing as table (Python)

Tags: python, multiple-columns, string-formatting, multilinestring

I want to rearrange sections of text into a text where these sections appear as columns.

Below the code I have came up with up to now:

```
sectSepar = '\n---\n'
mltiColmn = """\
Column A
first row
second row
3rd row
---
Column B
1. only
---
Column C
1. ...
2. long-long text"""

import itertools
print( *list(itertools.zip_longest(*[ 
   [ column.ljust(maxlen:=max(map(len, section.split('\n')))) 
       for column in section.split('\n') ]
           for section in mltiColmn.split(sectSepar) ],
           fillvalue=''.ljust(maxlen))),sep='\n')
```

The code works OK, but it prints:

```
('Column A  ', 'Column B', 'Column C         ')
('first row ', '1. only ', '1. ...           ')
('second row', '                 ', '2. long-long text')
('3rd row   ', '                 ', '                 ')
```

instead of

```
('Column A  ', 'Column B', 'Column C         ')
('first row ', '1. only ', '1. ...           ')
('second row', '        ', '2. long-long text')
('3rd row   ', '        ', '                 ')
```

I assume that the problem the code has is that Python evaluates the value of `maxlen` not as I would like it would do, but don't have an idea how to resolve the problem. Along with this I don't like the way the code is written as I am loosing the overview because of the nesting and hard to track brackets. So my question is:

Is there a way to write code for such text rearrangement that is easy to read and to understand (e.g. using chaining instead of nesting commands like `max(map(len ...)))` and which provides the right output?

Answer (score 0):

To go issues with deep nested list comprehensions out of the way I suggest to split the rearrangement into steps as follows:

```
colmnsAsTxtLines = """\
Column A
first row
second row
3rd row
---
Column B
1. only
---
Column C
1. ...
2. long-long text"""
sectSepar = '\n---\n'

import itertools
Rows = list(itertools.zip_longest(*[ section.split('\n') 
       for section in colmnsAsTxtLines.split(sectSepar)],fillvalue=' '))
print( *[ list(e) for e in zip(*[list(map(str.ljust, sectnLines, 
        [max(map(len,sectnLines))]*len(sectnLines))) 
        for sectnLines in zip(*Rows) ] ) ], sep='\n')
```

the code above gives the right requested output:

```
['Column A  ', 'Column B', 'Column C         ']
['first row ', '1. only ', '1. ...           ']
['second row', '        ', '2. long-long text']
['3rd row   ', '        ', '                 ']
```